# Open finder directory in terminal emulator of choice?

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, command-line, automation

I'm using a launcher app called Raycast which lets me run script commands anywhere. On their github I found community Applescripts that have functionality I want (opening current finder folder), but they're for iTerm or for the default macOS Terminal. When I try to change these scripts to my desired app, "Warp", I'm met with syntax errors.

In [this](https://github.com/raycast/script-commands/blob/master/commands/navigation/open-iterm-from-finder.applescript) script (below) I tried changing "iTerm" to Warp", the syntax error was "**Expected end of line but found class name**":

```
tell application "Finder"
    set pathList to (quoted form of POSIX path of (folder of the front window as alias))
    set command to "clear; cd " & pathList
end tell

tell application "iTerm"
    activate
    set hasNoWindows to ((count of windows) is 0)
    if hasNoWindows then
        create window with default profile
    end if
    select first window

    tell the first window
        if hasNoWindows is false then
            create tab with default profile
        end if
        tell current session to write text command
    end tell
end tell
```

Then in [this](https://github.com/raycast/script-commands/blob/master/commands/navigation/open-terminal-from-finder.applescript) script (below) I tried changing "Terminal" to Warp", the syntax error was "**Expected end of line, etc. but found "script"**":

```
tell application "Finder"
    -- Check if there's a selection; works if there's a window open or not.
    if selection is not {} then
        set i to item 1 of (get selection)

        -- If it's an alias, set the item to the original item.
        if class of i is alias file then
            set i to original item of i
        end if

        -- If it's a folder, use its path.
        if class of i is folder then
            set p to i
        else
            -- If it's an item, use its container's path.
            set p to container of i
        end if
    else if (window 1 exists) and (folder of window 1 exists) then
        -- If a window exist, use its folder property as the path.
        set p to folder of window 1
    else
        -- Fallback to the Desktop, as nothing is open or selected.
        set p to path to desktop folder
    end if

    set command to "cd " & quoted form of POSIX path of (p as alias) & ";clear;"
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    if not (exists window 1) then reopen

    activate

    if busy of window 1 then
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
    end if

    do script command in window 1
end tell

return ""
```

Sorry, I don't know much about Applescript, could somebody explain **why I cant simply change which app either of these scripts are using?**

Comment: I don't have access to Warp, but can you check if it handles scripting? You can check it with: `find /path/to/warp.app/Contents/Resources/ -name "*.sdef"`. You can  also `cd` in the current Finder location using function - example https://github.com/htr3n/zsh-config/blob/master/autoloaded/cdf

Comment: There is no .sdef file in resources, only an .icns file.

Comment: So it means that it doesn't have scripting implemented. Only "Standard Suite" that is common for all apps (like activate etc.). You can try to change those scripts in such a way that the command you'd like to  run is copied into pasteboard, pasted in Warp and simulate "return" keystroke.